# Cannot publish ASP.NET Web API to Azure App Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I am getting this error when I try to publish my ASP.NET Web API to Azure App Service.

> Publish has encountered an error.
> Be sure that the Startup.cs for your application is calling AddSwaggerGen from within ConfigureServices in order to generate swagger file. Visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=2131205&CLCID=0x409 for more information.

I cannot figure out the problem. Everything looks good to me.

ConfigureServices Function:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<StatsVal_APIContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("StatsVal_APIContext")));
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "StatsVal_API", Version = "v1" });
            });
            services.AddCors(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddPolicy(name: _policyName, builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });
        }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you also added `app.UseSwagger();` etc in your Startup.Configure method as denoted here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#add-and-configure-swagger-middleware

Comment: Yup, already had that.

Comment: Can you add the complete code for your Startup class, the Azure build command  you use in your pipeline & a screenshot of your error in azure pipelines (assuming you are using azure pipelines to build and publish your api app)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the latest version of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. Here is the the official workaround
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2006

Add a global.json file to your Web API project

Put this in it:

```
{ "sdk": { "version": "3.1.406", "rollForward": "latestPatch" } }
```

Comment: This didn't work, and I am running it on net 5.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem had something to do with the publish profile. I made a new one and it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: what was the problem with publish profile??

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue. There was another error message though, in my case it could not connect to the Azure Sql db. After revisiting the connection string, it connected successfully and the above error disappeared as well. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).